# On mobile browsers, the value of a CSS property change only at scroll's end

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I put some text to fill a website with some content.

- I want that after a user scrolls down on mobile (I tried with mobile Safari and Chrome - same results), a "scroll to top" button appears.
  The button should appear if I leave the top of the page, and hide if I'm at the top.
- This button have a smooth show/hide effect. I achieved this using CSS `opacity`.

### Question:

It works on Desktop, but on mobile the button instantly shows, without the smooth effect, waiting for the scroll movement to stop.
It does show on mobile when going from bottom to top. The smooth effect is maintained.

[Here](https://vimeo.com/190688300) you can see what I mean. I want a true smooth effect on all browsers, can you help me?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "it-IT">
    <head>
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing JavaScript</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...</p>
        <button id = "toTop" onclick = "goToTop()"><img... ></button>
        <script>
            var body = document.body;
            var toTop = document.getElementById("toTop");
            function goToTop() {
                body.scrollTop = 0;
            }
            window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
                if (body.scrollTop > 400)
                    toTop.style.opacity = 1;
                else
                    toTop.style.opacity = 0;
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#toTop {
    background-color: orange;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border: 1px solid black;

    img {
        width: 2em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when testing on desktop browser resized to mobile width?

Comment: @AllDani.com all is ok, like when the browser is at its full width

Comment: Maybe JavaScript is disabled on the phone used to test?

Comment: @AllDani.com but if it was disabled, also the viceversa effect (from bottom to top, that's show -> hide) would not work

Comment: Any chance you can post what it looks like? An image, or, better yet, a video? BTW if it helps, parlo Italiano. And just to be sure, double check about the JS being On. Can't hurt, right?

Comment: @AllDani.com ottimo! Un video ce l'ho, ma non avevo trovato come condividerlo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127583/discussion-between-alldani-com-and-rhshanks92).

Comment: Don't use `scroll` eventlisteners. On mobile devices these get triggered *after* scrolling, instead of during scrolling. Also, they are resource hogs. Use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead

Comment: @LuudJacobs the result doesn't change. I still have the button that brutally appear

Comment: @RHShanks92 yeah it does, there's no transition set to the element. add `transition: opacity 400ms ease-out;` to the button' css

Comment: @LuudJacobs pay attention: there's already that property to the element with `id = "toTop"`, that's the button. There's the `transition: 0.5s` property

Comment: @RHShanks92 You didn't specify what needed to be transitioned your CSS. And remove spaces from your tag-attributes. so `id="toTop"` instead of `id = "toTop"`.

Comment: @LuudJacobs the problem is still here, also specifying `transition: opacity 0.5s ease`